# Do too many console.logs affect Single Page application's/tab's memory and performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, single-page-application, console.log

I am building a single page web application(SPA). 
My team has an extensive habit of using console.log's for debugging. Since we work in an Agile project, our production code tends to accidentally carry forward some of these console.logs.

As a result of it, the App being an SPA, after a few minutes of transactions we end up with a few Hundred logs, in case we haven't hit refresh(F5).

Is the number of memory bytes allocated per browser tab limited and do these console log's eat into the memory otherwise allocated for the application?

Does this significantly affect the SPA's performance?

If yes,

Is doing this(below code) at the application scope level a good solution ?

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.clear();
}, 30000);
```

Also for Angular Js :
Does the $log service provide it's equivalent for console.clear()?

Answer (score 2):

I personally wouldn't worry about the performance issue, but I'd suggest being able to turn on and off the console.log in production if it is a viable option:

```
var loggerPlaceholder = console.log;
function turnOfLog(){
    console.log = function (){}
}
function turnOnLog(){
    console.log = loggerPlaceholder
}
if(isProduction()){
    turnOfLog();
}
```